# Do iPhones use active scanning to find Wi-Fi networks when Ask to Join Networks is off?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, security, scanning

I'm looking into security holes in my daily life, and I ran across [an article](https://www.crc.id.au/tracking-people-via-wifi-even-when-not-connected/) that says that most devices broadcast their MAC address continuously. I'm wondering if that applies to iPhones (and other iDevices) as well. I would expect them to use active scanning when Ask to Join Networks is on, or if you are actually in the Wi-Fi Settings (though I don't know that that is the case), but what about normally? Is my iPhone broadcasting its identity everywhere it goes as long as the Wi-Fi is on?

Comment: How would one's MAC address be used as a security hole?

Comment: Because it's unique to your device, so that you can be tracked from place to place. As the article I linked says, "basic analysis of this kind of data from a shopping centre can tell me what shops you visit or what areas you like to spend time in. I can tell how long you spend in my building – and where you enter and leave. I can tell how fast you walked from one end to the other. I can tell if you visited the bathroom. I can likely tell if you drove to my building – or took the bus. For me (or any scary three letter organisations), this information is pure gold."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [iOS8](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201395) the MAC is randomised while scanning for wi-fi networks. I believe that has since been adopted by most devices.

The REAL MAC is only used after connection to a network.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: See the WiFi section of Apple's [iOS Security Guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) (PDF). It says iOS 11 "uses randomized Media Access Control (MAC) address when conducting Wi-Fi scans ..."